# ASP.net MVC 5 application: one request generates multiple controller endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am debugging a weird issue with ASP.NET MVC 5 application. When one client request is fired, for instance myapplication/faq/company_id, it generates multiple faq controller endpoints in the trace.axd page.

```
33  1/27/2016 2:26:56 PM    /faq/4048950    200 GET View Details
34  1/27/2016 2:27:07 PM    /faq/4048950    200 GET View Details
35  1/27/2016 2:27:09 PM    /faq/4048950    200 GET View Details
```

The faq layout is nested under main site layout. I have made the faq layout very primitive.

Have anyone seen such or similar issue before? Any thoughts or suggestions to further debug this problem?

Comment: (Assuming your "snippet" is from Fiddler) If you were to "View Details", is this the same information being returned every time? If you put a breakpoint in your FAQ Action method, does it get hit 3 times for every request that is made? If so, it would help to see that logic.

Comment: Thanks Krillgar for your reply. I just kind of located the issue - let me know if this makes sense. Inside the layout file, it checks one data element (an image location) in ViewBag and creates link references in the page's <head>area.<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
        <link rel="address bar icon" href="" />

Comment: Not enough sense. You need to provide a LOT more detail in your question.

Comment: sorry, I am a new user of the forum, i didn't complete my comment last time. Basically the layout file checks one data element (img location) in ViewBag and creates link references in the page's <head>area. Because the value is empty for this company id, it generates two empty references shown below. Somehow it makes  the MVC application refer to  this page or hit the controller two extra times.